# Connect to a remote sql server without port forwarding

Tags: vpn, sql-server

On our main office we have a Windows 10 Pc that has Sql server. Here we have the database.
On another office ( that is not on local network ) we have another windows 10 Pc , with an application that use this database.
First we have configured access to database using Port forwarding on main office's router.
But after some time  , a hacker has attacked our main office , and we believe the reason was the open port on router.
I have read that the database can be accessed without port forwarding using VPN.
But i've never worked before with VPN. so i need to know how can i do this ? I need a VPN software to install on both computers or ???

Comment: You can use VPN  (been there, done that).  Get a consultant if you do not know. Then use VPN to get to the Office PC and run the database there. Do NOT attempt to run client server over VPN.

Comment: @John If you say Get a consultant , then what is the purpose of this forum.Because every question will be answered Get a consultant or IT.

Comment: VPN is complicated, and that is why you need a consultant to do it. There are numerous VPN setups.  I use a Hardware VPN box at the site and NCP Secure Entry to se it up. Long complicated answer and that is not the purpose of a simple Q&A forum.

Comment: I've read an article about creating vpn connections in windows without any third party software , but that method need port forwarding .

Comment: yes, some degree of port forwarding is required. there is basically nothing you can do without it. you are correct, it is dangerous to forward SQL ports to the outside world. the SQLServer is not designed to deal with all the dangers of being exposed to the Internet at large. Yes a VPN is your best bet if you can't get the server and the DB on the same site, but some port forwarding will be required for the VPN. as John points out, questions like "how do I set up a VPN" with no additional info are simply too broad for stack exchange sites. do your research and ask a more focused question

Comment: @FrankThomas ok , i did some research and found some articles that speak about creating a VPN server  and VPN clients on windows 10. But for VPN server it needs a port forward. I have a simple question : On the PC that have sql server should i configure as a VPN server and the Pc that has the software configure as vpn Client?

Comment: @alex I'd avoid messing around with VPN server software on your server PC + port forwarding. I'd stick with hardware. If your existing main office internet firewall doesn't support configuring a VPN on it, then upgrade the firewall to one that does. That can then handle the VPN, as well as (if the remote site has a static IP) lock down who can connect to it.

Comment: You are right, you were “hacked” because your server was accessible from outside of your network, but regardless if you use a VPN or make the servers directly accessible you will be exposing a server.  You will have to port forward traffic to a VPN by the way. Don’t run a VPN on the same server that’s running the database. You would just be exposing the database again.

Comment: @Ramhound but is there a way to configure vpn server  (without 3d party software)  without port forward ?

Comment: @alex - Regardless if you use a VPN server built-into hardware or configure a server from scratch you will have to port forward traffic to the VPN server otherwise it won't be accessible from outside of your network

Comment: @Ramhound So even with VPN , i'm not protected from hackers. So for my scenario the only more secure configuration : i need 1 Pc to be VPN Server , One Pc as vpn client to install SQL server , and another Pc as vpn client to run my software ? but again the vpn server is exposed to hackers.

Comment: @alex - I never said that. I just you will expose some risk. There are secure ways to implement a VPN which are virtually unhackable, it doesn’t seem, like you know what you actually want to implement.

Comment: ok you seem to be under the impression that all port forwarding is equally bad. that is not the case. some servers are designed to be exposed to the Internet, like webservers and VPN servers, but others are not (like SQLServer). forwarding a port for a hardened service that is made to be publicly accessible is very very different than exposing a backend service that has not been fully hardened. Next, I think your best bet is to create an infrastructure (site-to-site) VPN connection between the remote office router and the main office router. that is probably the simplest and most reliable.